# email logs SMTP - Base table or view not found

Tags: magento-2.1, smtp

I have installed extension SMTP from Mageplaza https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/

In the "logs" panel I should have all messages sent as in the screenshot below.
[image]

But in my magento I have error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'b2b_style.mageplaza_smtp_log' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mageplaza_smtp_log` AS `main_table`
```

[image]

Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: setup:upgrade + cache:clean ?

Comment: There is not a lot to go on. Did your `bin/magento setup:upgrade` complete without errors?

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be because of something happens wrong while installing this extension. Or setup script has something wrong.
So Open table `setup_resource` and find module for `Mageplaza_Smtp`, delete that row and try running commands:

```
PHP bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

It will create table. Please put die Inside setup script to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Do `setup:upgrade` and cache clean / flush.
If that wont work check version of module in module and check module version in database (table `setup_resource` and look for Mageplaza_Smtp module).
If version is the same and `mageplaza_smtp_log` table is not exist in DB, then try to uninstall module (using Uninstall Script).

Otherwise try to recognize where exactly in Setup/Install.php or Upgrade.php file in module is script creating this table and revert module version id DB to this version - then use again `setup:upgrade` and clear cache or just run script creating table manually.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try

```
composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: You do not do a composer update on a Magento shop unless you mean to perform a magento update. If you think your `composer.lock` may be out of sinc with you `composer.json` you can do a `composer update --lock`